# Pointer doesn't point to the correct location, after parsing it as an argument

Tags: c#, pointers

```
internal unsafe struct Array<T>
{
    public int Length;

    internal nuint* ptr;

    public Array(int capacity)
    {
        ptr = (nuint*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(capacity * sizeof(nuint)); // allocates memory on heap
        Length = capacity;
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index > Length || index < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));
            nuint PointerToT = ptr[index]; // gets pointer to type
            byte TFirstByte = *(byte*)PointerToT; // gets the first byte of the type
            return Unsafe.As<byte, T>(ref TFirstByte); // converts byte to type

        }
        set
        {
            if (index > Length || index < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));
            void* valueAsPtr = Unsafe.AsPointer(ref value); // gets pointer, but gets the wrong address
            ptr[index] = (nuint)valueAsPtr; // sets pointer at index
        }
    }
}
```

what I'm trying to do is make my own sort of array, but when I try to get the pointer to the memory address of the value that I'm setting, I get the pointer location of the parameter: 'value' but not the actual value. Is there a way to get the memory address of the value before it has been parsed as an argument.

```
Array<int> myArray = new(1);
int v = 21;
myArray[0] = v;

int* ptr = &v;
```

this is how I'm trying to use it but the address that the 'ptr' variable gets is not the same as the address that it has in the setter. I have used other data types like strings, but those have the same issue.

```
Console.WriteLine(myArray[0])
```

and once i try to get the value, it tries to read the memory of the 'value' parameter which was in the setter, but this is not available anymore.

Comment: Which pointers are you comparing?

Comment: `myArray[0] = v;` this is copying the value, not the pointer.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I know but I'm trying to get the address the 'value' parameter within the setter of the struct, and not outside.

Comment: The problem is that you get a copy of the valuetype value in the `value` argument. This way the compiler is preserving the original value before the method call. pushing it on-top of the stack. And popping it afterwards back. Even with a pass by ref argument, is that you still have a copy of the pointer (but pointing to the same address). If you want to pass a pointer, you should pass a real pointer.